# How can I improve formatting of floats output from my tax calculator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator, number-formatting

I didn't have any problems writing this much, but the output numbers are a little wonky. Sometimes I'll get something like 83.78812, for example, and I'd rather round it up to 83.79.

Here's the code itself:

```
#This is a simple tax calculator based on Missouri's tax rate.

while True:
tax = 0.076
cost = float(raw_input("How much does the item cost? $"))
taxAmount = tax * cost
final = taxAmount + cost
if cost > 0:
    print "Taxes are $" + str(taxAmount) + "."
    print "The total cost is $" + str(final) + "."
else:
    print 'Not a valid number. Please try again.'
```

I've seen people mention that I should be using ints instead of floats, but my tax-rate is over three characters past the decimal. Furthermore, typing in a string results in an error that crashes the program, but I'd rather it simply give an error message and loop back to the beginning. I don't know how to fix either of these things.

Answer (score 1):

> "typing in a string results in an error that crashes the program, but I'd rather it simply give an error message and loop back to the beginning."

To do this, you can use a while loop with `try & catch` That will keep on prompting for the item cost until it gets appropriate value

Use `round()` method to round up your value. It takes two parameters, first one is the value and second one is the position where to round up.

Format your result with python string formatting using the placeholder `%.2f` (2 digits after decimal point)

```
tax = 0.076
cost = 0
parsed = False
while not parsed:
    try:
        cost = float(raw_input("How much does the item cost? $"))    
        parsed = True
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid value!'
taxAmount = tax * cost
final = taxAmount + cost
if cost > 0:
    print "Taxes are $%.2f." % round(taxAmount, 2)
    print "The total cost is $%.2f." % round(final, 2)
else:
    print 'Not a valid number. Please try again.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **round**:

```
round(final,2)
```